# Counting objects with a same property value

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8, java-stream

I'm creating a poker rank solver and I have to count cards with same suit or same rank in a set of cards. Here I create `HashMap` and increment value if multiple ranks are in the set.

```
private boolean isFourOfAKind() {
        Map<RANK, Integer> rankDuplicates = new HashMap<>();
        for(Card card : cards) {
            rankDuplicates.put(card.getRank(), rankDuplicates.getOrDefault(card.getRank(), 0) + 1);
        }
        return rankDuplicates.containsValue(4);
    }
```

I was wondering is it possible using streams do exact same things with java streams. It would look something like this:

```
    private boolean isFourOfAKind() {
        Map<RANK, Integer> rankDuplicates = cards.stream()
            .map(Card::getRank)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(/*...something goes here..*/)); // of course this is very wrong, but you can see what I'm aiming at.
        return rankDuplicates.containsValue(4);
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for something like

```
return cards.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Card::getRank, e -> 1, Integer::sum))
        //                        keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction
        .containsValue(4);
```

OR if you don't have to use `Collectors.toMap` you can use more readable way which uses `Collectors.groupingBy` like shown in [Holger's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809846/counting-objects-with-a-same-property-value#comment47761893_29810080)

```
return cards.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Card::getRank, Collectors.counting())
        //creates Map<RANK, Integer>, the Rank --> amount mapping
        .containsValue(4);
```

Comment: to me, `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Card::getRank, Collectors.counting())` looks cleaner…

Comment: @Holger Actually to me too. Wasn't aware of it while posting this answer and created code based on current and limited knowledge. Anyway you seem to know a lot about Java 8. Can I ask where does your knowledge come from? Can you recommend good source of information about it beside official tutorial (books or sites/articles)?

Comment: @Pshemo: unfortunately, I don’t remember having read something being substantially better than the official material, so I have no recommendation at hand. It’s just playing around with it for two years now and since trying to answer an SO question implies engaging in it, every question make me better ☺ and I answered almost four hundred of them, not counting the ones I have read and thought about, but not answered because someone else was faster…

Comment: @Holger Thank you for your response. "*It’s just playing around with it for two years now*" so it seems that you ware interested in Java 8 even before it was officially released (which was in march March 2014). That kind of makes sense and explains your knowledge :)

Answer (score 5):

Another variant with `groupingBy`:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;

...

private boolean isFourOfAKind() {
    return cards.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Card::getRank, counting()))
                .containsValue(4L);

}
```

Basically you group the card by the ranks so that you have a `Map<Rank, List<Card>>`

Then you use the downstream collector `counting()` to map each list to its number of elements, so that the final result is a `Map<Rank, Long>` (you could also use `summingInt(i -> 1)` instead of `counting()` if you really need to have a `Map<Rank, Integer>`).

Comment: As an addendum, if `Rank` is an `enum`, using `.collect(groupingBy(Card::getRank, ()->new EnumMap(Rank.class), counting()))` might be slightly more efficient.